# StreamReader vs BinaryReader?

Tags: c#, .net, file, streamreader, binaryreader

Both `StreamReader` and `BinaryReader` can be used to get data from binary file ( for example )

*BinaryReader :*

```
   using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"c:\1.bin",FileMode.Open))
            {
                    byte[] data = new BinaryReader(fs).ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);
                    Encoding.getstring....
            }
```

*StreamReader  :*

```
  using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"c:\1.bin",FileMode.Open))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs,Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                       var myString=sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
```

What is the difference and when should I use which ?

Comment: One is suitable for text files, the other for binary files? As you even elude to in your sample code.

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth  utf8 string can contain binary data also.

Comment: Yes, but presumably encoded as a UTF-8 string... so in essence would be text.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth isnt a utf8 string can hold any info ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir "utf8 string can contain binary data" - what do you consider "binary data" ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman for eaxmple : view jpeg content in total commander

Comment: @RoyiNamir - you mean control chars and bytes outside the ASCII range?

Comment: @Adam Houldsworth: Both streams & byte arrays can hold binary data. Binary files can also be read/written via disk or even via network sockets with either method. See `GetStreamAsync` & `GetByteArrayAsync` methods of `System.Net.Http.Httpclient` as an example.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

> Both StreamReader and BinaryReader can be used to get data from binary file

Well, `StreamReader` can be used to get text data from a binary representation of text.

`BinaryReader` can be used to get arbitrary binary data. If some of that binary data happens to be a representation of text, that's fine - but it doesn't have to be.

Bottom line:

- If the entirety of your data is a straightforward binary encoding of text data, use `StreamReader`.
- If you've fundamentally got *binary* data which may happen to have *some* portions in text, use `BinaryReader`

So for example, you *wouldn't* try to read a JPEG file with `StreamReader`.

Comment: but a utf8 string can contains inside it even binary data.. so... ?

Comment: isnt a utf8 string can hold any info ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: No, a string is text. There's not even such a thing as a "UTF-8 string" - there's a UTF-8 *binary representation* of a string... A string holds text data - it's a sequence of characters. You then convert that to a binary representation using an encoding, such as UTF-8. Please read http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Unicode.aspx

Comment: as you may know they all inherits from the base class stream, so there is no difference to use one of those.

Comment: @jon what im saying is that there isnt a binary charcter which i cant save it in string... so i can get the bin content to string via StreamReader and BinaryReader

Comment: @Nudier: No, neither StreamReader nor BinaryReader derive from Stream. There is *absolutely* a huge difference between using StreamReader and using BinaryReader.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: "Binary character" is a contradiction in terms. It's like talking about a "floating point integer". You **must not** read arbitrary binary data (e.g. a JPEG file) as text. You *will* lose information.

Comment: @jon ok ... one final thing : ive just read a jpeg file using binary reader -byte array size was 740. than i read via streamreader - to a string - string .length was still 740.... so...?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Are you converting it into text in a naive way in both cases? If so, you're probably losing data in both cases, possibly consistently. Just don't do it - binary data *isn't* text, so don't try to pretend it is. If you really need to represent arbitrary binary data in text, use base64.

Comment: @JonSkeet i got my problem. unicode is only for text. i thought it could also represent some ugly charcters . this was the source of my mistake. thanks.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Unicode can represent almost any *character* you care to mention. But the key word here is *character* - not *byte*. Characters are for text. If you haven't got text, you haven't got characters.

Comment: @giorgim: Well that's why you can lose data. And fundamentally it's just a bad idea to treat data of one form as another - it encourages you to perform all kinds of inappropriate operations on it.