# HTML doesnt work when i copy paste into another document

Tags: html, vb.net

I have written some HTML with notepad, when i open it with IE it works fine and loads the google map on the page. 
I have then converted that text into vb.net stream writer. when it creates the html document it wont load the google map. but, if i copy the html that the application creates and paste it into a html document i make with notepad it works fine.

Whats going on?

I use

```
Using writer As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter("C:\CarPosition" & Loc & ".htm", True)
```

to write the bulk of the HTML

and i have a loop in the application to write an array, i use the following line to do that:

```
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\CarPosition" & Loc & ".htm", vbNewLine & "['Car:" & CarNumber & "'," & " -" & LatsDecimal & "," & " " & LongsDecimal & ", " & Count & "],", True)
```

I want to know if vb.net writes some hidden characters in text documents or notepad does? because if i analyse the two html documents they are identical, one loads correctly in IE and one doesnt.

thanks,

Mike

Comment: WriteAllText has an optional encoding parameter. Play with that field :)

Comment: "it won't work" doesn't tell us anything

Comment: @DerekTomes is most likely correct.  Play with the encoding parameter.

Comment: I tried every encoding type available, none of which worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tips:

- Do a binary diff between the two files to find the difference. [You can do it online](http://www.diffnow.com/?url1=http://www.diffnow.com/demo/1.bin&url2=http://www.diffnow.com/demo/2.bin)
- Check BinaryReader for reading the file in the first place https://stackoverflow.com/a/10353961/390330