# C# - Browse Folder and Binary Reader

Tags: c#, folderbrowserdialog, binaryreader

I am having difficulty getting Binary Reader to detect the files selected from a "Browse for Folder" dialogue. The intent is to read at "X" location within all files in a directory and save that data to a TXT file. I've tried various ways but cannot seem to get it... The line I'm having trouble with is:

`BinaryReader NDSRead2 = new BinaryReader(file)`

Anything I put in to replace `(file)` throws an error. Tried various ways with that line and elsewhere in my code but can't seem to get it. My code is listed blow.

```
 /// OPEN FOLDER DIALOGUE      
        FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        fbd.Description = "Select a folder";
        fbd.ShowNewFolderButton = false;
        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
           /// THIS NEXT CHUNK OF CODE SETS UP WHERE THE TXT FILE WILL BE SAVED, IN THE SELECTED DIRECTORY.
            string brlTextLoc = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(fbd.SelectedPath);
           txtBRLSave = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fbd.SelectedPath + "BuildRomList.TXT", true);

            txtBRLSave.WriteLine("Build Rom List");
            txtBRLSave.WriteLine("Using The Rom Assistant v0.57");
            txtBRLSave.WriteLine();


          /// THE LOOP FOR EACH FILE TO BE READ IN FOLDER BEGINS.
            FileInfo[] files = dir1.GetFiles();
            System.IO.StreamWriter txtBRLSave;
            foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(fbd.SelectedPath, "*.EXT"))
            {

                BinaryReader NDSRead2 = new BinaryReader(file);

            /// THE ISSUE I HAVE IS WITH "(FILE)" ABOVE... IT KEEPS GETTING FLAGGED IN RED NO MATTER WHAT I PUT IN THERE.

           /// BELOW CONTINUES THE BR CODE, AND TXT SAVING CODE, WHICH ISN'T NEEDED FOR THIS QUESTION AS I KNOW IT WORKS.
```

Comment: `BinaryReader` takes a `Stream` not a filepath `string` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Try :StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file); BinaryReader NDSRead2 = new BinaryReader(reader);

Comment: Are you sure you need a binary reader and not a StreamReader? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353913/streamreader-vs-binaryreader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the string into a stream as follows

```
foreach(string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(...
{
    using(var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open))
    using(var NDSRead2 = new BinaryReader(stream))
    {
       // do you stuff
    }
}
```